# TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

am trying to do a route system with react and react-pose for animating route and parsing the location object return me an error can you please help me ?? this is the code the error is in the Routecontainer

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Route, NavLink} from "react-router-dom";

import "./App.css";
import HomeComponent from "./Components/HomeComponent"
import ContactComponent from "./Components/ContactComponent"
import AboutComponent from "./Components/AboutComponent"
import NavBar from "./Components/NavigationBar"
import posed, {PoseGroup} from "react-pose";


const RouteContainer = posed.div({
    enter: { opacity: 1, delay: 300, beforeChildren: true },
    exit: { opacity: 0 }
});

class App extends Component {

  render() {
      let {location} = this.props;
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
           <div>
               <NavBar/>
               <PoseGroup>
                   <RouteContainer key={location.key}>
                       <switch location={location}>
                           <Route path="/" component={HomeComponent}/>
                           <Route path="/About" component={AboutComponent}/>
                           <Route path="/Contact" component={ContactComponent}/>
                       </switch>
                   </RouteContainer>
               </PoseGroup>
           </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Which React router version are you using? What do u get if you do console.log(this.props.location)

Comment: I am using the version 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the location object outside of a Route Component. Since you are using `<BrowserRouter>` inside the App Component, the `HomeComponent`, `AboutComponent` and `ContactComponent` will have access to the location object but not `<App />`.

You can read more about where react-router provides the location object [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location)

You can work around this by creating a wrapper component that returns the following:

```
return (
   <BrowserRouter>
     <Route path="/" component={App} />
   </BrowserRouter>
);
```

And you can then remove the `<BrowserRouter>` bit from inside `<App />`
 Component. The path `/` will match on all the routes since `exact={true}` is not passed as a prop.